# Using Nginx as a proxy for Jenkins using Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm using Nginx as a proxy for Jenkins server. Both in Docker container.

The idea is Jenkins running on port 8080, with port 8080 exposed. Nginx listening on port 80 and redirecting traffic to Jenkins on port 8080. If you try to access port 8080 directly it will refuse the connection.

Please see docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    master:
        build: ./jenkins-master
        networks:
          - jenkins-net
        volumes:
          - jenkins-log:/var/log/jenkins
          - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home

   nginx:
      build: ./jenkins-nginx
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      networks:
        - jenkins-net

networks:
 jenkins-net:

volumes:
 jenkins-log:
 jenkins-data:
```

Jenkins-master Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine
LABEL maintainer=''

USER root
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
USER jenkins

ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx8192m'
ENV JENKINS_OPTS=' --handlerCountMax=300 -- logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war'
```

This is the nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log off;

   location / {

   proxy_pass         http://master:8080;

   proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
   proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;


   proxy_connect_timeout      150;
   proxy_send_timeout         100;
   proxy_read_timeout         100;

   proxy_buffer_size          8k;
   proxy_buffers              4 32k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

 }

}
```

this is my jenkins-nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY jenkins.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx"]
```

Adding Nginx Dockerfile for completeness:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY jenkins.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx"]
```

Jenkins.conf file:

```
daemon off;
user nginx;
worker_processes 2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
   use epoll;
   accept_mutex off;
}

http {
include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
default_type application/octet-stream;
log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" ';


  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  sendfile    on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  client_max_body_size  300m;
  client_body_buffer_size  128k;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/javascript application/json;
  gzip_disable 'MSIE [1-6]\.';
  gzip_vary on;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

 }
```

The problem is both works independently but as soon as I try to connect them on one network they crash.

Error throws `localhost refused to connect` on both services

Comment: It looks like nginx is listening on port 80 and proxying "/" to 127.0.0.1:8080, I think you want http://master:50000. If nginx is going to proxy, then you also probably don't want to map your jenkins container to a local port.

Comment: The idea is Jenkins running on port 8080, with port 8080 exposed. Nginx listening on port 80 and redirecting traffic to Jenkins on port 8080. Docker network that is exposed on port 50000 that connects them both.

Comment: I'm getting that error when rebuilding the image using `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Jenkins is in 1 container actually running on port 8080, nginx is in the other container running on port 80.  You have port 80 in the nginx container mapped to port 80 on the host machine. Nginx should then forward traffic to the jenkins container which would *not* be 127.0.0.1.  Instead you could just use the service name and port, like *master:8080*

Comment: Why are you using **build: ./jenkins-master** ? Are you using a custom jenkins  instead the official Jenkins Dockerfile?

Comment: @JRichardsz  Yes, I'm changing the public image in the Dockerfile. All I'm doing is defining environmental variables on that image which only affects how much RAM it uses and how much CPU it uses when it runs in the container. Not changing it in the way that would affect connectivity to other services.

Comment: Ok. Your goal is to have a public domain for your jenkins? Just that?

Comment: My goal is to go to localhost on port 80 (Nginx) and it redirects me to Jenkins login page on port 8080. If you try to access Jenkins on port 8080 directly without using Nginx it will refuse the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the configuration that worked in my case:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    master:
        build: ./jenkins-master
    networks:
      - jenkins-net
    volumes:
      - jenkins-log:/var/log/jenkins
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home

nginx:
    build: ./jenkins-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./jenkins-nginx/nginx.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - jenkins-net

networks:
  jenkins-net:

volumes:
  jenkins-log:
  jenkins-data:
```

Nginx-Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine

COPY ./jenkins.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx"]
```

Jenkins-Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine
LABEL maintainer=''

USER root
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
USER jenkins

ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx8192m'
ENV JENKINS_OPTS=' --handlerCountMax=300 --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war'
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log off;

    location / {

   proxy_pass     http://master:8080;

   proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
   proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;


   proxy_connect_timeout      150;
   proxy_send_timeout         100;
   proxy_read_timeout         100;

   proxy_buffer_size          8k;
   proxy_buffers              4 32k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

   }

}
```

jenkins.conf:

```
daemon off;
user nginx;
worker_processes 2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
  use epoll;
  accept_mutex off;
}

http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" ';


   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
   sendfile    on;
   keepalive_timeout  65;
   client_max_body_size  300m;
   client_body_buffer_size  128k;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/javascript application/json;
  gzip_disable 'MSIE [1-6]\.';
  gzip_vary on;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose port 8080 on your docker-compose

```
ports:
  - 8080
  - 50000:50000
```

This may help in nginx (jenkins.conf)

```
proxy_redirect http://master:8080/;
```

Comment: I updated my question to reflect changes to the code.

Comment: Would you check if the jenkins container port 8080 connects to nginx port 80?
On the nginx server, if you have netcat installed, run:
`nc -zv master 8080`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you publish the master and nginx on port 80. This is way too much. Just publish port 80 on nginx. The other ports on master are not needed, except you want to bind this port 50000 on your local address and port.

Container in the same network can resolve the names and reaches their ports without being published. Keep in mind Container cannot call localhost to reach your host. It would just solve the container itself. Use the container names inside the configurations and container itself.

UPDATE:

I've setup my configuration like the following. This worked for me.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    master:
        image: jenkins/jenkins:alpine
        networks:
          - jenkins-net
        volumes:
          - jenkins-log:/var/log/jenkins
          - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    nginx:
      image: nginx:alpine
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ./nginx.conf
          target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      networks:
        - jenkins-net

networks:
  jenkins-net:

volumes:
  jenkins-log:
  jenkins-data:
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log off;

    location / {

        proxy_pass         http://master:8080;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout      150;
        proxy_send_timeout         100;
        proxy_read_timeout         100;

        proxy_buffer_size          8k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

    }

}
```

Then i was able to call http://localhost and worked as expected. Hope it works as expected and you can adapt it to your personal needs.

Comment: Btw. What do you mean with docker network is exposed on 50000? What is your scenario?

Comment: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name=Jenkins-master --network Jenkins-net --mount source=xyz -d Jenkins/Jenkins`  It creates and runs container with Jenkins image exposing the port 8080 and connects it to "Jenkins-net" network. But the tutorial I'm following doesn't clearly say what and why we're doing 50000:50000 port exposure ?

Comment: I checked it quickly. Looks like 50000 gives you and remote (Java) API port. Did you try my advice?

Comment: I did, Manuel, but no change. Still getting the same error. Plus I'm getting `invalid parameter` on the line with proxy pass and proxy redirect. Looks like I'm not supposed to be passing names of the services.

Comment: This is a proper torment. Both services run fine on their own but as soon as I build them with `docker-compose` and exposing the right ports and run them it crashes.

Comment: I'm gonna help you. Let me try when I'm back home. I'm pretty sure it's just a small thing we don't see right now. I setup an nginx proxy with Jenkins and docker in our company. It's just some time ago. Inside the same docker network it can resolve the names of other container.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel Polacek  I'm gonna keep working on it. If you try it for yourself it's also a good practice for yourself, isn't it ?

Comment: I just ran `docker-compose up --build` and while rebuilding the image it threw at the end:  `nginx_1   | 2019/08/03 14:02:41 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "jenkins-master" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf:8
nginx_1   | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "jenkins-master" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf:8`

Comment: Sorry for my late response,  just arrived home and tried my composition.

Comment: Hi @Manuel Polacek  Thank you for sharing the config file. However I'm getting `localhost refused to connect` on both ports. 8080 and 80. I'll provide all files so you can review the files and pin point "there's your bug !".

Comment: Please check once if something else is running and blocking those ports. Sounds like the ports are already in use. This is my whole setup and got it running. A nginx proxy is usually nothing special. As you can see the setup is very straight forward. It has to do something with your local system.

Comment: I figured it may be a firewall but I checked and it's off on this machine.

Comment: I've been doing this on Mac so I'm gonna try my Ubuntu machine to see if I get different behaviour.

Comment: I just used the same configs and dockerfiles on my Ubuntu machine it gives me the same error. On Ubuntu it says `Unable to connect` which is just an equivalent to `localhost refused to connect`.

Comment: That's so strange. I don't get it. What happens, if you remove all the published ports?

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after I changed the name for jenkins.conf with nginx.conf. Also I have used this git repo: https://github.com/lucasp90/jenkins-nginx and it worked fine.